# Notepad to Excel column conversion - How to Parse one mixed string to 2 different column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel, notepad, data-partitioning

I have data in notepad with more than 1000+ entries, which need to convert in to Excel with particular break based on length. can someone help
011000015FRB-BOS           FEDERAL RESERVE BANK OF BOSTON      MABOSTON                   Y Y20040910

File format is as below
Position Field
1-9       Routing number
1         Office code

I tried delimiting option but dint worked out.

Answer (score 0):

If your data always has the routing number in columns 1-9, then delimited import is the way to go. Choose Import From Text, then select Fixed Width and click Next. On Step 2, click at each character that would be a separator. Eg, click at character 9 to split it into two columns with the first column haviong the first nine characters and the second column having the rest. Step 3 will allow you to set the data format. I'd recommend setting the first column to text so Excel doesn't try to use scientific notation or something on your account numbers.